# php mysql UPDATE tinyint set chosen 1 and rest 0

Tags: php, mysql, enums, sql-update

My php mysql-code is strange.

This works from time to time, sometimes it set all the values to 0 when i execute this line of code.

```
$tid = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['themes']));
$sql = ("UPDATE ai_themes 
         SET chosen = IF(tid!='$tid', '0','1')");

mysql_query($sql);
```

And sometimes just over the night all the values are 0.
Haven't looked at the enum types yet just curious why it is so...

The table for themes:

```
tid = int, PK, NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT
name = varchar(30)
chosen = tinyint(1)
```

[EDIT]

Mm, it seems as i dont get a valid value from the select form:

```
<form action="my_form_handler.php?c=3" method="post" data-transition="slideup">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="themes" class="select">Select theme:</label>
        <select name="themes" id="select-theme">
        <option value="1">Red</option>
        <option value="2">Green</option>
        <option value="3">Orange</option>
            <option value="4">Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
        <button type="submit" data-theme="a" name="submit" value="submit-value">Change theme</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Can't see any errors...

Comment: htmlentities - is it required there ? & what is the value in $_POST['themes'];

Comment: No but, one can never be too carful...

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the WHERE part here pal... without it it matches ALL rows in your table

Comment: that is what he is trying to do? he wants to update the chosen theme to 1, so all others have to be set to 0..

Comment: without knowing the rest of the code, there is plenty room for error... a themes value not matching ANY of the present `tid` will lead to `chosen=0` on all rows in the table... and this is exactly what he is describing.

Comment: For the moment 'tid' is hardcoded in a select statement on the html side.

Comment: which means nothing.... NOTHING which comes from the user side is safe.... nothing you can depend on. do you check if `$_POST['themes']`contains a "valid" value?

Comment: Seem's that i don't get any value right now, but i know it has worked before... Gonna post the code in my question...